# I got stucked in middle of the problem. How to find the value of radius 'x' cm from the given figure?

Tags: geometry, circles

[image: Problem description]

Firstly, I calculated the area of sector $AOB$ by applying  $\frac{1}{2}\times (1.2\ \text{radians})\times 20^{2}$ (formula for area of sector of circle) and calculated area of sector $AOB= 240\ cm^2$, tried bit of construction by joining $PC$ and $CR$ thus reaching $CP \perp AO$ and $CR \perp CR$. Also, tried Joining $PR$ to form $\triangle POR$ but couldn't have the idea to find the value of '$x$'. Give it a try.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! Please consider taking the time to read the [faq] to familiarise yourself with some of our common practices. In addition, [this page](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/8348) should give you a start at learning how to typeset mathematics here so that your posts say what you want them to, and also look good. As this question appears to be homework, please consider reading [this page](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1803/8348) for information about asking _effective_ homework-related questions. Cheers!

Comment: How can I type symbols and other advanced forms here? @Darksonn

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/), 
[here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/155238), 
[here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/) and 
[here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Comment: Really helpful. [link](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** $$\sin \angle COR = \frac{x}{20-x}$$

Comment: if we join OSCQ, are OA and OSCQ line segment equal in length? and does OSCQ bisect angle AOB?

Comment: you can compare triangles COR and COP (you already made perpendicularity statements).

Comment: and "If two circles touch one another internally, and their centers are taken, then the straight line joining their centers, being produced, falls on the point of contact of the circles."

Comment: finally, S seems undefined and useless.

Comment: oh, i finally got it, triangles COR and COP can be shown congruent with each other by R.H.S axiom.

Comment: yeah its useless here(to find the value of x) but it was for finding the perimeter of region PSRO(naming arc PSR)

Answer (score 0):

In right $\triangle CPO$, we have
$$\sin\frac{\angle AOB}{2}=\frac{PC}{OC}\quad (\text{since}\ \angle AOB=1.2\ \text{radians})$$ 
$$\implies \sin\frac{1.2}{2}=\frac{x}{20-x}$$ $$\implies x=20\sin 0.6-x\sin 0.6$$
$$\implies x=\frac{20\sin 0.6}{1+\sin 0.6}$$ $$\implies \color{blue}{x\approx 7.217527109\ cm}$$